Custom Routing Class using Angular 17
I've been using angular 17 for a while but routing system has changed a lot. I want to to add a custom class extended from @angular/router.
import {
  Event,
  EventType,
  Router,
  RouterEvent,
} from "@angular/router";
import { filter } from "rxjs";

type Category = "application" | "login" | "settings";
const pageRegexp = /^\/app\/(map|settings|operation)(?:\/|$)/;

export class CustomRouter extends Router {
  private category: { previous: Category | null; current: Category | null } = {
    previous: null,
    current: null,
  };

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.events
      .pipe(filter((event) => event.type === EventType.NavigationEnd))
      .subscribe(this.handleCategoryChange);
  }

  private handleCategoryChange(event: Event) {
    const url = (event as RouterEvent).urlAfterRedirects;
    const match = pageRegexp.exec(url);
    const currentCategory = match ? (match[1] as Category) : null;

    if (currentCategory) {
      this.category.previous = this.category.current;
      this.category.current = currentCategory;
    }
  }

  public getCategory() {
    return this.category
  }
}

I provide my routes in the app.config.ts using provideRouter(routes).
I want to use my custom class in instead of the default routing class
Does anyone have an idea ?
Thanks

please share what you are trying to achieve by doing this, you need to create a service that calls router. this is just a simple class, dependency injection will not even work!

If you want to just have a service that will store category for you, you don't need to extend Router. I would even say it's bad idea, because even if you extend it correctly, you're vulnerable to errors if something changes in router.
If you still want to do it, you can just add Injectable decorator, and you're good to go.
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})    
export class CustomRouter extends Router { 

You can inject it to your components and services now.
But you can achieve the same result without actually extending the router. All you need to do is to inject router to your class, something like this:
export class CustomRouter {
  private category: { previous: Category | null; current: Category | null } = {
    previous: null,
    current: null,
  };

  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }
  
  public init() {
    this.router.events
      .pipe(filter((event) => event.type === EventType.NavigationEnd))
      .subscribe((event) => this.handleCategoryChange(event)); // I added arrow function here, otherwise you could have issues with 'this' in handleCategoryChange method
  }

  private handleCategoryChange(event: Event) {
    const url = (event as RouterEvent).urlAfterRedirects;
    const match = pageRegexp.exec(url);
    const currentCategory = match ? (match[1] as Category) : null;

    if (currentCategory) {
      this.category.previous = this.category.current;
      this.category.current = currentCategory;
    }
  }

  public getCategory() {
    return this.category
  }
}

And just make sure you run init() method somewhere at start of your application. You can use APP_INITIALIZER for that - https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER.
Add something like this to your app.module or bootstrapApplication:
{
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: (customRouter: CustomRouter) => { customRouter.init(); },
  multi: true,
  deps: [CustomRouter],
},

You have the same effect without extending the router - I don't see any downsides. You just need to make sure that
